# Remove "Blocks" in "Format" button dropdown menu in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I have this "Format" toolbar button in tinymce, and I just want to know if there's a way to configure it's dropdown list items and how.

For now I have "Headers", "Inline", "Blocks" and "Alignment",
and I want to remove "Blocks".

Thanks in advance :)

Here's a screenshot of what I want to remove:

[tinymce dropdown menu item http://imageshack.com/a/img34/2654/wr2h.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img34/2654/wr2h.png)

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old but it appears an answer was never provided. The following will create a custom format menu for the toolbar in TinyMCE 5.0

```
tinymce.init({
style_formats: [
    { title: 'Headers', items: [
      { title: 'Heading 2', block: 'h2' },
      { title: 'Heading 3', block: 'h3' },
      { title: 'Heading 4', block: 'h4' },
      { title: 'Heading 5', block: 'h5' },
      { title: 'Heading 6', block: 'h6' }
      ]
    },
    { title: 'Blocks', items: [
      { title: 'Paragraph', block: 'p' },
      { title: 'Div', block: 'div' },
      { title: 'Blockquote', block: 'blockquote' },
      { title: 'pre', block: 'pre' }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
tinymce.init({
menu: { 
    file: {title: 'File', items: 'newdocument'}, 
    edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall'}, 
    insert: {title: 'Insert', items: '|'}, 
    view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'}, 
    format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'}, 
    table: {title: 'Table'}, 
    tools: {title: 'Tools'} 
}
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's for the menu bar. (which in this case, is hidden).

What i'm trying to modify is the "Format" option in the toolbar.

Anyways, thanks for trying to help @Rahul :)